# Forward traffic between interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables

I have a home router with an Internet connection. I also have a computer which is in a place where I cannot connect it directly to the router.
Hopefully, I have two raspberry pis that I didn't know what to do with.

I'd like to achieve these results:

[image]

The IP of my computer cannot be changed as it is used by other devices on the router network.

So far, I've been able to do the following communications (IPs have been set with `ifconfig`):

| Command | Pi #1 | Pi #2 | Computer | Any device on HomeRouter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ping 192.168.0.1 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE (Subnet is different) |
| ping 192.168.0.2 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE (Subnet is different) |
| ping 192.168.1.1 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| ping 192.168.2.1 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE (Subnet is different) |
| ping 192.168.1.100 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| ping 192.168.2.100 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE (Subnet is different) |
| ping 192.168.1.102 | OK | OK | OK | NOPE |
| curl 8.8.8.8 | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| curl google.com | OK | OK | OK | OK |

The following command lines have been executed on both PI:

```bash
# Enable IP forwarding
echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

# Masquerade outgoing packets
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# Add DNS
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

- On PI #1, I've added the following route:

```bash
# Set static IP for both interfaces
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig ppp0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

# Add routes
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.0.2 dev ppp0 # Route packets to Pi #2
```

- On PI #2, I've added the following route:

```bash
# Set static IP for both interfaces
ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig ppp0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0

# Add routes
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0 # Route packets to Pi #1
```

- On my computer:

```bash
# Set static IP
ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.100 netmask 255.255.255.0

# Add routes
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1

# Add DNS
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

I've tried to add a second IP on the eth0 interface of the first PI. The plan is to redirect all packets coming to `192.168.1.102` to `192.168.2.100`.

```bash
# Add a new IP to PI #1's eth0
ip addr add 192.168.1.102 dev eth0

# Masquerade IP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.102 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -s 192.168.2.100 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.102
```

Would that work ?

Comment: Does the computer specifically need to have an 192.168.1.x address? Are there any "auto discovery" features that must work across this connection? There are two different options depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I do not know the IP of the computer. It can be set via DHCP or static (including subnetwork 192.168.1.0/24)

Comment: Without having spent too much thought on it (just looking at the IPs you've used) I'd say the main issue is that you're trying to have `192.168.1.0/24` on either side of `192.168.0.0/24` ... you shouldn't need iptables, just enable routing on both pi's and make static routes for each endpoint on all devices.

Comment: Do you have any clue on the `ip routes` I need to set ?
Would it be easier if PI #2 eth0 was a DHCP server ?

Comment: I've updated my question with some routes but I don't master this kind of commands. Could you have a look please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same network number to exist on both ends, routing generally will not be enough.

In general, you need to remember that there is another layer of addressing that exists below IP. On Ethernet (and Wi-Fi), all packets are delivered to a specific MAC address – before your Pi can forward a packet it needs to *receive* that packet, and that'll only happen if the sender knows (either via ARP or via its routing table) that it needs to send the packet towards the Pi.

Your attempt to add /32 routes is a good start, but doing so on the Pi only helps if the packets get delivered to the Pi to begin with – currently, devices in the "left" 192.168.1.0/24 network do not know they need to send packets via the Pi#1's MAC.

In other words, your home router doesn't automatically know that 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.Y are behind another router – it's configured to assume that the entire /24 is "on-link", answering ARP replies.

This could be finished in two ways: either adding the same kind of /32 route via Pi#1 on "Home router" (as well as all other devices that would be connected to "Home router"), or configuring Pi#1 to perform **proxy ARP**, i.e. answering ARP queries on behalf of IPs that it doesn't directly have.

I would generally go for proxy ARP in this case; it can be set up via `ip neigh add ... proxy` on Linux (and/or the `proxy_arp` sysctl, which appears to be orthogonal to manually added proxy-neighbor entries), but the userspace `parpd` daemon is a bit easier to configure.

With proxy-ARP in place, when your home gateway (or some computer) tries to send packets to 192.168.1.Y, it will learn Pi#1's MAC address through ARP and will direct the packets there. You should do the same on the other end, providing proxy-ARP responses to PC Y on behalf of the rest of the /24.

**Bridging** would probably be a much better approach to the overall problem. You could set up a VXLAN or EoIP tunnel between both Pi's (basically Ethernet-over-IP), bridge the tunnel interface to the physical Ethernet interface, and you would literally have a single subnet stretching across from home router to computer Y, with everything (including ARP, IPv6, etc.) being forwarded at MAC layer.

Bridging could also be achieved without a tunnel if the Wi-Fi interfaces on the Pi support "4addr" mode; the AP is always bridgeable but the station needs to have 4addr mode activated to become bridgeable, and the AP must be configured to accept 4addr frames. In this case, the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet would be no longer needed; it would just be 192.168.1.0/24 all the way through.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question using Bridging. Could you please take a look and let me know if I understand correctly the concept ?

Comment: You have the general idea right, but you forgot the actual _bridging_ part, with using `bridge` or `brctl` to configure a L2 bridge between eth0 and eoip0. But as far as I know Linux doesn't have a literal `eoip` tunnel type (sadly), so you would need to use [VXLAN](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-vxlan-linux) which is point-to-multipoint but serves nearly the same purpose. (Mikrotik RouterOS has GRE-style EoIP though.)

Comment: I've updated my code to use VXLAN. Could you have a quick look ?

Comment: I've updated my question with NAT rules to redirect an IP to another. Could you have a quick look please ?